# Changing NSFetchedResultsController's fetchRequest.predicate does not trigger delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I've got a `NSPredicate` on my FRC's `fetchRequest`.  At some point an object is added to CoreData, I create a new predicate, update the `fetchRequest` and perform a fetch:

```
self.fetchedAddressesController.fetchRequest.predicate = self.predicate;
BOOL success = [self.fetchedAddressesController performFetch:nil];
```

This does however not invoke the FRC's delegate methods like `controllerWillChangeContent:`.  And my table view is not updated.

However, when I add the following line:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

below the two shown above, I do see the expected update.  This shows that the data to be displayed has indeed changed.

I've checked the new predicate and it's fine.  I also set FRC's `delegate` to `self`, and its methods are invoked in other cases.

Any ideas already what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you have described is expected. According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW34), if you want to modify a fetch request on a NSFetchedResultsController, you must delete the cache (if you are using one), modify the NSFetchRequest, then invoke performFetch: (which won't call any of the delegate methods).

If you want to know what has changed between the predicates, you need to store the old state and compare. A library that I've used in the past for this is [Doppelganger](https://github.com/Wondermall/Doppelganger).

Comment: I did consult this documentation, but I did not readily found it saying that the delegate methods were not called.  Where can I find that?  On the contrary I read: 'Memory-only tracking: ... updates section and ordering information ...'.

Comment: See the section "Modifying the Fetch Request" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW23

Answer (score 0):

The delegate methods are called when the FRC observes changes to the set of fetched objects it has eyes on after you do a fetch. If you go and change the predicate and do a new fetch, the FRC is reset and is now observing a different set of objects. The delegate methods aren't called because nothing changed in the original set of objects.

Answer (score 0):

## Careful if you are literally changing the entity...

We had a tricky one, not only the sort changed but the actual entity class changed, so for two different tab buttons,

```
let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CD_Cats")
```

but then ..

```
let r = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CD_Dogs")
```

In fact if you're doing that, THIS will NOT work:

```
func buttonLeft() {
    mode = .cats
    bringupFetchRequest()
    pull.feedForCats() // get fresh info if any at the endpoints
}

func buttonRight() {
    mode = .dogs
    bringupFetchRequest()
    pull.feedForDogs() // get fresh info if any at the endpoints
}
```

It will eventually crash.

## It seems you need this:

```
func buttonLeft() {
    mode = .cats
    bringupFetchRequest()
    tableView.reloadData()
    pull.feedForCats() // get fresh info if any at the endpoints
}

func buttonRight() {
    mode = .dogs
    bringupFetchRequest()
    tableView.reloadData()
    pull.feedForDogs() // get fresh info if any at the endpoints
}
```

That (seems to) reliably work.